# Django error 183 (Windows XP)

Tags: django

Command

```
@"D:\Program Files\Python26\Lib\site-packages\django\bin\django-admin.py" startproject mysite
```

causes error 183 without any useful information. System path is set properly. What I need to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Windows error 183](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#error_already_exists) means that a file already exists. Your project (or something that django is trying to create) is already there.

I can reproduce the error by creating the same project twice in a row:

```
C:\TestFolder>django-admin.py startproject error183project
```

Now, do it a second time:

```
C:\TestFolder>django-admin.py startproject error183project
Error: [Error 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists: 'C:\\TestFolder\\error183project'
```